# Is there a functorial way to define the cone of a finite type k variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is there a functorial way to define the cone of an finite type k variety?  Mostly I want there to be so that it is obvious how this construction would glue together, though if forced to I think I see in principle how one would go about doing this by embedding the varieties individually in affine space.

Comment: What does cone mean here?

Comment: @Hoot I mean the construction that takes an affine variety in $A^n$, embeds it in $A^{n+1}$, picks a point not on the image of the variety (say, $(0,0, \ldots, 0, 1)$ and builds the union of all lines through the variety and that point over it. I think this recipe does pretty much tell one how to go about consistently assigning cones to the affine patches (take $spec k[A^n] / I \times spec k[t]$, mod out by something), in a way that I *think* glues, but it is not sufficiently canonical that I would feel comfortable saying that it obviously glues.